# Sending html code

Tags: javascript, html

Well for example i have such not really safe and correct form

```
    <BODY>
<FORM ACTION="" METHOD="post" NAME="test" ID="test">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="testt" VALUE="1">
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="testtt" onClick="test.submit()">
</FORM>
```

its vulnerable on injection i know but its on purpose. When i'm sending html code directly from page with form its interpreted as html code. 
But when I'm using script from [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit) its printed as plain text i was trying to conver text to html entities but its still printed as plain text, how coudl i send html code using that script which will be interpreted as html code and injection will be possible ?

Comment: i mean i can send form in two ways directly from page with that form or using script which i mentioned in question when i do it directly on page its interpreted as html <script> document.body.style.background = "red";</script> just change bg color to red when i'm using script from url its interepreted as plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok my solution was adding backslashes to some special characters and adding `CONTENT="text/html;`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an html parser like [this one.](http://ejohn.org/apps/htmlparser/)